# In a Blazor Server Side app is it possible to access UserManager<IdentityUser> in another service?

Tags: c#, blazor

In a Blazor Server Side app is it possible to create a service that can access UserManager? I tried the below code but it did not work. I don't know how to pass the parameter or even if it is possible. I tried several combinations

```
Program.cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext....
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>...
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AppWithUserManager>(????????);

AppWithUserManager.cs
public class AppWithUserManager()
{
   private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

   public AppWithUserManager(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
     {
         _userManager = userManager;
     }
}
```

Comment: On the server `.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(...` adds the user manager. You cannot access the user manager in the client(wasm). If you have inherited `IdentityUser` like the template does you need to inject with the same type `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`

Comment: Where is this placed  UserManager<ApplicationUser> ?

Comment: Where you are trying to gain access to the user manager. In your case the constructor of the `AppWithUserManager`. The `AppWithUserManager` will still need to be added as a service. However you cannot inject a transient service into a singleton. It will have to be of the same scope or less.

Comment: @Brian Parker
  Ok. It is working now. I also changed the scope level as you mentioned in the comment.  If you may place it as an answer I can close the thread.